# given a small set of points in 2d, how to draw circles that does not overlap around each of them so that their radius is maximized?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, computational-geometry

A farmer has n goats. Coincidentally, he also has n fixed posts in a field where he wants the goats to graze. He wants to tie each goat to a post with a length of rope. He wants to give each goat as much leeway as possible – but, goat ropes are notorious for getting tangled, so he cannot allow any goat to be able to wander into another goat’s territory. What is the maximum amount of rope he could possibly use? (There will be at most 50 goats in this problem)

I don't know how to solve this problem after thinking for a while. Thanks for answering.

(Original problem:https://open.kattis.com/problems/goatropes)

Comment: I think you need to insist that each goat is given a *non-zero* length of rope, otherwise you can just pick one goat to have an arbitrarily long rope, give the rest zero, and you're done.

Comment: Have you considered Voronoi diagram/Delaunay triangluation?

Comment: @mbo but will that maximize what we want maximized?

Comment: @AakashM I am not sure

Comment: @MBo For three points forming a triangle the maximal solution is a configuration with pairwise touching circles which run through the points where the inscribed circle touches the triangle sides. A Voronoi diagram would give the center of the circumscribed circle - so it does not seem helpful here.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the case with 2 poles only p1, p2 lying at a distance d(1,2). Let's call r1 the length of the rope that is for the goat at pole 1, r2 the length of the rope for the goat that goes on pole 2. Then the simple relation is:

```
r1 + r2 <= d(1,2)
```

If we add a third pole (and one goat more) then we can add two more relations:

```
r1 + r3 <= d(1,3)
r2 + r3 <= d(2,3)
```

It is obvious how to proceed with n poles and n goats. In any case it will lead to `(n x (n-1)) / 2` inequalities as above. Now lets try maximizing the size of the total rope. Total rope will be

```
R=r1+r2+r3+...+rn
```

Now the problem is formulated as:

```
Maximize R=r1+r2+r3+...+rn
```

Subject to the constraints:

```
ri + rj <= d(i,j)  where i<j
```

This is a classic formulation of a Linear Programming problem, search for Simplex or any other suitable algorithm.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you for the edits!.  I am still wondering if there is another way to solve it, not requiring to solve a Linear Programming problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I think linear programming is the correct approach if an exact solution is desired. If an approximate solution is acceptable, then techniques like genetic algorithms could be used.